# Data not showing from data table in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

I want to show the data already entered in a page while editing.

This is my blade file

```
<form class="" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="choice_form">
    <div class="row gutters-5">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            @csrf
            @method('PUT')
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h5 class="mb-0 h6">{{translate('Requirement Information')}}</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-md-3 col-from-label">{{translate('Product Name')}}</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="{{ translate('Product Name') }}" value="{{ $rfq->name }}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="mar-all text-right">
                    <button type="submit" name="button" value="publish" class="btn btn-primary">{{ translate('Update Requirement') }}</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

@endsection
```

This is my Controller

```
use App\Models\Category;

use App\Models\Requirement;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $rfq = Requirement::find($id);
        $categories = Category::where('parent_id', 0)
            ->where('digital', 0)
            ->with('childrenCategories')
            ->get();
        return view('requirement.edit', compact('rfq','categories'));
    }
}
```

This is my model code

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Requirement extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'name'
    ];
}
```

This is my route

```
<?php


Route::get('/edit/{id}', 'ProductController@edit')->name('requirement.edit');
```

This is my Data Table

[image]

The data is successfully entered in the data table

Answer (score 0):

Sir, Your Routes are wrong set. In laravel 8 Routes are changed.

You can See Here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#the-default-route-files

I have changed your routes to laravel 8 styes routes. You can try below code.

```
Route::get('/edit/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\ProductController::class, 'edit'])->name('requirement.edit');
```

Comment: this code i have downloaded from codecanyon this is the code of laravel 7

When Laravel 8 came, the coders are updating this code, but for now the routes will be in the way of Laravel 7

While editing the code, I came to know that there was a mistake in my calling activity.

Answer (score 0):

Add all columns in fillable variable

```
 protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'name',
        'added_by',
        'user_id',
        'category_id',
        'photos',
        'quantity',
        'description',
        'status',
        'unit',
        'slug'
    ];
```

And Your Routes are wrong to set. In laravel 8 Routes are changed.

```
Route::get('/edit/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\ProductController::class, 'edit'])->name('requirement.edit');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Looking at your form in action the route, do it like this:**

```
<form class="" action="{{ route('requirement.edit), $rfq->id }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="choice_form">
<div class="row gutters-5">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        @csrf
        @method('PUT')
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h5 class="mb-0 h6">{{translate('Requirement Information')}}</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-md-3 col-from-label">{{translate('Product Name')}}</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="{{ translate('Product Name') }}" value="{{ $rfq->name }}">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="mar-all text-right">
                <button type="submit" name="button" value="publish" class="btn btn-primary">{{ translate('Update Requirement') }}</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```